# jquery fade from - to

Tags: jquery, fade

I like the whole jQuery.fadeOut things and all that, But what I constantly want to do (without fiddling around with stupid CSS) is just set a state to fade FROM, and then to.

All i know how to do is this:

```
$(".hoverTest").hover(
function () {
    $("#user").fadeOut(100,function () {$("#mydiv").html('foo');}).fadeIn(); 
},
function() {
    $("#user").fadeOut(100,function () {$("#mydiv").html('bar');}).fadeIn(); 
            }
);
```

And this, of course, upon moving the mouse of a .hoverTest object will fade #mydiv to foo, and then on mouse out fade to bar.

But what i'd like to be able to do in jQuery is cut out the fade out, change div, fade back in methodology and just set a state to fade the current div *to*.

Is this possible/anyone know a way/understand what I mean? :)

EDIT:

So, effectively, if you were to pause the animation at 50%, you would see both states (from & to) at 50% opacity.  If this hasnt been done somebody should do it or get it added into jQuery.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ ?

Comment: no because that doesnt help - It just fades to a given opacity - I want to fade the content of a div STRAIGHT TO some other content, without fading out and fading back in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the answer!**

I did a bit of maths (it was fun this one, because i solved it) And this is the eventual function I needed to come up with.  Set an `<a>` tag with a class of `hoverInfo` and then the bar 'users' (or whatever you want to call it) will seemingly crossfade between the two with the new information being gathered from  the 'rel' statement.  Or data. or whatever. :P

**js-fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/8h5CW/

**jQuery code:**

```
$(".hoverInfo").hover(
    function () {
        var tmpInfo = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#hoverInfo").css("display","none").html(tmpInfo);
        var dW = $("#defaultInfo").outerWidth();
        var hW = $("#hoverInfo").offset().left + $("#hoverInfo").outerWidth();
        var defX = $("#defaultInfo").position().left; 
        var newPos = (defX-(hW-dW));
        $("#hoverInfo").css("left",newPos+"px");
        $("#defaultInfo").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#hoverInfo").fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function() {
        $("#defaultInfo").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#hoverInfo").fadeOut(1000);
    }
);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="users" style="position: relative; display: block; border: 1px solid #00f; width: 500px; padding: 10px; height: 20px;">
    <span id="defaultInfo" style="position: relative; float: right;">
    I would like this to fade out yes.</span>
    <span id="hoverInfo" style="position: absolute;"></span>
</div>
```

After testing on my site, For some reason in the page that I wanted to use it on I had to reset the .LEFT each time, so instead of:

```
$("#hoverInfo").css("display","none").html(tmpInfo);
```

I just changed it to:

```
$("#hoverInfo").css("left","0px").css("display","none").html(tmpInfo);
```

If anyone can think of a quicker, smarter way to do this, I would love to know about it.

**Thank you for your answers, and I hope this helps somebody else.  I shall be using this function alot in the future**

Comment: Okay, so how about having a .hoverInfo class on an element, and the hover to data in rel="", and fading to that, instead of setInterval and multiple <p>'s?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, that way it'll be more generic. Only thing maybe I would use a `data-` attribute and a `.data()` method to get the info

Comment: aha i was not aware of that particular attr.  The problem I am having now is that the text needs to be right aligned, and with an absolute element I can only position from the top right and left. :S

Answer (score 0):

Just fade in and out at the same time instead of one after the other.  In your example, the fadeIn only happened after the fadeOut completed since it was defined in fadeOut's callback function.

```
$(".hoverTest").hover(
function () {
    $("#user").fadeOut(100)
    $("#mydiv").html('foo').fadeIn(); 
},
function() {
    $("#user").fadeOut(100)
    $("#mydiv").html('bar').fadeIn(); 
});
```

Comment: can you show an example in jsfiddle? i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the issue. Do you mean you want to do something like this?  element.fadeTo(element2)

Comment: yeah so, instead of fading out, changing the data, fading in - just a smooth continuous fade from the current data to the next?